# How to check processes CPU usage history in macOS

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My MacBook Pro ran into something weird this afternoon, it'll freeze for a few seconds every few minutes. I didn't run anything unusual. When I open the Activity Monitor, sometimes I can catch a huge spike on the CPU usage after it just passed. But there is no way for me to tell which processes caused those spikes.

So I'm wondering if there is any way for me to check process's CPU usage history.

P.S. By freezing I mean the mouse cursor still moves but nothing is responsive.

Comment: Running High Sierra?

Comment: Nope, version 10.12.6.

Comment: In that case, use Console. It registers everything including hung tasks and excessive resource usage.

Comment: can you be more specific by using Console? when the freeze happens nothing is usable so I can only check back records afterwards.

Comment: You could filter on timestamp and see events during the hang

Comment: Thanks, I never used Console before so I was not clear, now I see how the tool is used. I'll have it open if this happens again. I guess this should at least give me clue what caused the problem. You can give an official answer and I'll accept.